# Symfony/Doctrine relations good practice

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I have entity `User` and `Location` - something like shop, and i need to add relations between them, but i dont know what is good practice for this, because:

User can have 3 types: Manager, Supervisor or employee, and:

- Every Location have one user as manager, one manager has one location;
- Every Location have one user as supervisor, one supervisor has many locations;
- Every location have many users as employees, one employee has one location;

First thought is that add relations to user:

```
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Location", mappedBy="supervisor")
     */
    private $locations;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Location", mappedBy="manager")
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Location", inversedBy="employees")
     */
    private $wrokLocation;
```

and on location:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="locations")
     */
    private $supervisor;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="location")
     */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="wrokLocation")
     */
    private $employees;
```

But i dont know is it the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly I would do an abstract class User, then 3 classes Supervisor/Manager/Employee which extends User class. The relations to Location would be in each classes instead of User class.

Then in Location you can targt these classes.